# ggboxplot ignoring factor levels

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-grid, factors, ggpubr

I have made a `ggboxplot`, which I am very happy with, except that the order of my x-values has been changed. The x-values are factors for which I have defined the level. However, in the plot this order is different. I imagine that the order might be conflicting with other factor levels set or with the nested facets, but I can't seem to fix it.

[image: ggboxplot]

The code for plotting:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)
library(ggh4x)

#setting levels:
counts_fe_d7_long$day <- factor(counts_fe_d7_long$day, 
                                levels = c("WT", "vanA", "inoculum"))
counts_fe_d7_long$inoculum <- factor(counts_fe_d7_long$inoculum,
                                     levels = c("WT", "vanA", "vanA narAB"))
counts_fe_d7_long$fe_group <- factor(counts_fe_d7_long$fe_group,
                                     levels = ("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8")) 

#plotting:
p_d7_log <- ggboxplot(data = counts_fe_d7_long,  #generate plot
                      x = "fe_group", 
                      y = "CFU_g_log",
                      color = "day",      #coloring of boxes
                      palette = "jco",    #nature of colors used
                      add = "jitter",)+   #dispersing points so they don't overlap 
  theme(panel.border = element_rect(linetype="dotted",color="grey", fill=NA), 
        panel.spacing = unit(0, 'pt'), legend.position="right",
        strip.text = element_text(size = 7,margin = margin()))+
  # "margin" for space in facet boxes, 
  # "stri.text" for text size in box and "panel.spacing" for space between boxes.  
  labs(x = "group", y = "log(CFU/g+1)",color = NULL)+
    # "free" argument removes empty space in the plot. 
    # In contrary to facet_grid, facet_nested allows for merger of facet boxes. 
  facet_nested( ~ inoculum + treatment,scales = "free_x", space = "free_x" ) 

p_d7_log
```

Data:

```
counts_fe_d7_long <- 
structure(list(inoculum = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), levels = c("WT", "vanA", 
"vanA narAB"), class = "factor"), treatment = c("-", "-", "-", 
"-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "narasin", "narasin", 
"narasin", "narasin", "narasin", "narasin", "narasin", "narasin", 
"narasin", "narasin", "narasin", "narasin", "-", "-", "-", "-", 
"-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "narasin", "narasin", 
"narasin", "narasin", "narasin", "narasin", "narasin", "narasin", 
"narasin", "narasin", "narasin", "narasin", "-", "-", "-", "-", 
"-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "narasin", "narasin", 
"narasin", "narasin", "narasin", "narasin", "narasin", "narasin", 
"narasin", "narasin", "narasin", "narasin", "monensin", "monensin", 
"monensin", "monensin", "monensin", "monensin", "monensin", "monensin", 
"monensin", "monensin", "monensin", "monensin", "lasalocid", 
"lasalocid", "lasalocid", "lasalocid", "lasalocid", "lasalocid", 
"lasalocid", "lasalocid", "lasalocid", "lasalocid", "lasalocid", 
"lasalocid"), ID_1 = c("1x", "1x", "1x", "A", "A", "A", "B", 
"B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "2x", "2x", "2x", "D", "D", "D", "E", 
"E", "E", "F", "F", "F", "3X", "3X", "3X", "G", "G", "G", "H", 
"H", "H", "I", "I", "I", "4X", "4X", "4X", "J", "J", "J", "K", 
"K", "K", "L", "L", "L", "5X", "5X", "5X", "M", "M", "M", "N", 
"N", "N", "O", "O", "O", "6X", "6X", "6X", "P", "P", "P", "Q", 
"Q", "Q", "R", "R", "R", "7X", "7X", "7X", "S", "S", "S", "T", 
"T", "T", "U", "U", "U", "8X", "8X", "8X", "V", "V", "V", "W", 
"W", "W", "X", "X", "X"), fe_group = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L), levels = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8"), class = "factor"), day = structure(c(3L, 
2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 
1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 
3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 
2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 
1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 
3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L), levels = c("WT", 
"vanA", "inoculum"), class = "factor"), CFU_g = c(0, 173000, 
27699827000, 0, 94700, 30799905300, 0, 55600, 9439944400, 0, 
66200, 3709933800, 0, 7.5e+08, 6.75e+09, 0, 1610, 5140, 0, 6670000, 
60030000, 0, 33200000, 108800000, 0, 6210000, 30993790000, 878000, 
110000, 21999012000, 309000, 140691000, 5.629e+09, 1060000, 13040000, 
3075900000, 4500000, 159500000, 1.026e+09, 3090000, 208910000, 
0, 25700, 4864300, 1405110000, 19600, 12680400, 1457300000, 131000, 
1179000, 11298690000, 66700, 83300, 3829850000, 32900, 241100, 
6589726000, 0, 60000, 0, 81800, 24418200, 16400000, 50000, 149950000, 
0, 0, 314000, 11986000, 0, 1.38e+08, 7.5e+07, 2e+07, 1.23e+09, 
8.75e+09, 726000, 5809274000, 2.9e+09, 132000, 608868000, 0, 
365000, 254635000, 6.1e+07, 0, 9960000, 9340000, 0, 1.37e+08, 
9.8e+07, 0, 56300000, 56700000, 0, 6210000, 0), CFU_g_log = c(0, 
5.23804861349427, 10.442477056691, 0, 4.97635456498204, 10.488549381198, 
0, 4.74508260256365, 9.97496943641565, 0, 4.82086454972976, 9.56936616025739, 
0, 8.87506126397076, 9.82930377289536, 0, 3.20709554041922, 3.71104760386703, 
0, 6.82412589902816, 7.7783683505905, 0, 7.5211380967852, 8.03662889935384, 
0, 6.79309167011127, 10.4912746861418, 5.94349501054646, 5.04139663327193, 
10.3424031766336, 5.48995988490632, 8.14826631960226, 9.75043124873736, 
6.02530627497635, 7.11527762470069, 9.48797221223478, 6.65321261028522, 
8.20276069011605, 9.01114736119909, 6.48995861997319, 8.31995923114904, 
0, 4.40995002162051, 6.68702044097571, 9.14771032492243, 4.29227822867297, 
7.10313298772028, 9.16354896519982, 5.11727461086816, 6.07151417345327, 
10.0530280931899, 4.82413234502939, 4.92065021499472, 9.58318176482667, 
4.51720909818954, 5.38219901167808, 9.81886735712396, 0, 4.77815848856469, 
0, 4.91275861286237, 7.38771366433642, 7.21484387452907, 4.6989786901388, 
8.17594647299181, 0, 0, 5.49693103117446, 7.07867430959394, 0, 
8.1398790895483, 7.87506126918229, 7.3010300173787, 9.08990511179248, 
9.94200805307195, 5.86093721890145, 9.76412186095135, 9.46239799804871, 
5.1205772213031, 8.78452315034899, 0, 5.56229405430274, 8.40591809961771, 
7.78532984213035, 0, 6.99825938202756, 6.97034692272843, 0, 8.13672057032644, 
7.99122608012407, 0, 7.75050840256528, 7.75358306655242, 0, 6.79309167011127, 
0)), row.names = c(NA, -96L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

Comment: Probably (I didn't try - sorry for being lazy!) 'treatment' needs to be assigned to a factor with its levels as well.

Comment: @MatteoCastagna. Thanks. My issue is that the order is interrupted though:  c("-","narasin","-","narasin","-","narasin","monensin","lasalocid")

Comment: @MatteoCastagna. I solved it by assigning pseudo names to the "treatment" variable ("A","B","C" etc) and then later change these labels in the facet. Thank you so much for guiding me in the right direction. I am very grateful!

Answer (score 1):

You need to reorder your `treatment` column based on `fe_group`;

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)
library(ggh4x)
library(dplyr)

counts_fe_d7_long %>% 
  mutate(day = factor(day,  c("WT", "vanA", "inoculum")),
         inoculum = factor(inoculum, c("WT", "vanA", "vanA narAB")),
         fe_group = factor(fe_group, c("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8")),
         treatment = factor(treatment, unique(treatment[order(fe_group)]),
                                       ordered=TRUE)) %>% 
 ggboxplot(x = "fe_group", y = "CFU_g_log",
           color = "day", palette = "jco", add = "jitter") +   
  theme(panel.border = element_rect(linetype="dotted", color="grey", fill=NA),
        panel.spacing = unit(0, 'pt'),
        strip.text = element_text(size = 7, margin = margin()),
        legend.position = "right") +
  labs(x = "group", y = "log(CFU/g+1)", color = NULL) +
  facet_nested( ~ inoculum + treatment, scales = "free_x", space = "free_x")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2024-03-24 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>